# how do I get a count of an array based on a nested attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `user` array with an `invitations_attributes` array inside of it. The `invitations_attributes` array has another array inside of it. Here is the structure:

> `"user"=>{"invitations_attributes"=>{"6"=>{"email"=>""}, "7"=>{"email"=>""}, "0"=>{"email"=>"asdf@gmail.com"}, "1"=>{"email"=>""}, "2"=>{"email"=>""}, "3"=>{"email"=>""}, "4"=>{"email"=>""}, "5"=>{"email"=>""}}}}`

What I want to do is get a count of `invitations_attributes` where the `email` value is not blank. So in the above case, the count would be 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you show is a nested hash, not an array. Given a `user` hash as you describe:

```
user["invitation_attributes"].count{ |key, value| value["email"].present? }
```

Comment: this worked! can you explain why you put item[1] there? how come that is a variable?

Comment: I revised the answer. If you only pass in one argument to a block on a hash, it'll give you arrays, so the first one would have been `["6", {"email" => ""}]`, so the item at location 1 would be `{"email" => ""}`. However, the better way is to give two arguments, the key and value, and then you can just check the value.

Comment: hmmm...very interesting. I will have to review how this works but it worked great. thanks so much!